# Multinomial model on victim reporting behaviour

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to fit a multinomial logit model on the data below. I want to see whether gender, age, population and the province have an influence on the reporting behavior of a victim of crime. This is my model:

```
library("mlogit")
#source("~/Forge/mlogit/chargement.R")

R <- mlogit.data(data, shape="wide", choice = "choice_of_reporting")
m <- mlogit(choice_of_reporting ~ gender_household_head + age_household_head 
             + pop + prov_name, R)
summary(m)


mlogit(formula = choice_of_reporting ~ gender_household_head + age_household_head 
          + pop + prov_name, data = R, method = "nr",
          print.level = 0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[4,4] = 0
```

Can someone tell me what this error mean and how I can solve it?

Thank you for your assistance!

An extract from my data:

```
          DEPENDENT VARIABLE               GENDER             AGE     POP   PROVINCE
           Did not report                     1                 56    black EASTERN CAPE
5566       SAPS and other                     1                 42    black EASTERN CAPE
5567   Other but not SAPS                     0                 66    black EASTERN CAPE
5568            SAPS only                     0                 68    black EASTERN CAPE
5576            SAPS only                     0                 60    black EASTERN CAPE
5584       SAPS and other                     0                 76    black EASTERN CAPE
5600            SAPS only                     0                 35    black EASTERN CAPE
5611            SAPS only                     1                 68    black EASTERN CAPE
5612            SAPS only                     0                 52    black EASTERN CAPE
5615       Did not report                     0                 46    black EASTERN CAPE
5667   Other but not SAPS                     1                 59    white EASTERN CAPE
5668   Other but not SAPS                     1                 59    white EASTERN CAPE
5685       Did not report                     0                 24    black KWAZULU-NATA
5689       Did not report                     0                 62    black KWAZULU-NATA
5697            SAPS only                     0                 71    black KWAZULU-NATA
5698       Did not report                     0                 63    black KWAZULU-NATA
5703       Did not report                     0                 85    black KWAZULU-NATA
5704       Did not report                     1                 59    black KWAZULU-NATA
5705       Did not report                     1                 81    black KWAZULU-NATA
5708       Did not report                     1                 42 coloured KWAZULU-NATA
5709       Did not report                     0                 33    black KWAZULU-NATA
5721       SAPS and other                     1                 46    black EASTERN CAPE
```

Comment: How many observations do you have? This could mean there is not enough information in your data to fit a model with many covariates, try first with simpler models! Also, why do you use mlogit? Did you try glm, in base R?

Comment: It might also help if you can show us the frequencies for the different variables.

Answer (score 1):

All of your independent variables are individual-specific, but your syntax has specified them as alternative-specific. Check the `mlogit` documentation for the use of `|` to separate these categories. I think this is what you should have:

```
mlogit(formula = choice_of_reporting ~ 0 | gender_household_head + age_household_head 
          + pop + prov_name, data = R, method = "nr", print.level = 0)
```

Also see: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf